# Create bottom toolbar using xamarin form for android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, toolbar

There are good numbers of post of this but not of them are simple one. One of them is below one which is look simple https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/add_a_nav_bar_bottom_toolbar/

I am new to xamarin and currently using xamarin form to develope an cross plate form app. It looks above example is using xamarin native not xamarin form? Can same example will work for xamarin form? Or for this kind of UI manipulation xamarin native is better than xamarin form. As i am new to xamarin, should i focus on xamarin native instead of xamarin form for serious app development.

Thanks,

@paul

Comment: the sample above is for Xamarin.iOS.  If you want to work on xamarin.forms , maybe you can use custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Please click [here](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF) for Bottom Navigation Bar for Xamarin Forms. 
This will look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could build it on your own with a ControlTemplate.
No CustomRenderer is needed.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating/

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Just copy paste all the documentation stuff from the link in a fresh project. It is self explaining. You can create a static container and reference this in all views you need it.